# Modificar formulario admin de Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework, django-admin

¿Hay alguna forma de modificar la estructura de los campos de un Modelo en el administrador de Django?

De tal manera que los campos(F000, F001, F010, FO11, F012) se visualicen en forma Horizontal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias usar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798197/django-admin-form-how-to-show-two-fieldsets-horizontally-in-a-form